# Can I populate a field on an onChange event?

Tags: python, xml, onchange, odoo

I am trying to show the user a list of possible amenities when the user choses a Hotel from a form.

For that I have a `fields.selection` field with the Hotels Names and based on the selection I want to populate a notebook I also have in the same view with a `fields.one2many` field which would need to grab the amenities for the specific hotel from the amenities table.

Can I use the `onChange` event to populate a different field from the one that is *changing*?

I am a little confused as how can I achieve this. Any tip will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can:

Your XML would be:

```
<field name="hotel" on_change="hotel_change(hotel, context) />
<field name="other_field" />
```

Your method would be (remove context from method signature if version < 7.0):

```
def hotel_change(self, cr, uid, ids, hotel, context = None):
   other_field_value = get_other_field_value(hotel)
   return {'value': {'other_field': other_field_value,},}
```

Note:

1. This is for 7.0.  If your OpenERP version < 7.0 remove the context from the XML on change attribute and the hotel_change method signature.
2. The return from an `on_change` is a dictionary containing (possibly):

   - 'value' - a dictionary of fields and values
   - 'warning' - a dictionary with two fields, title and message  This becomes like an `osv.osv_except` back to the user.
   - 'domain' - a domain.
3. You can return any other field on the form/tree in value.
4. You do not need to return the passed in hotel in the value but if there is an error or you want to change it you can return it.
5. If you return "other_field" in value and `other_field` also has an `on_change`, that `on_change` will be called.